# Творительный падеж для составных названий

Tags: падежи

Как будет правильно звучать должность **инженер-программист** в творительном падеже?
Оба ли слова склоняются или только последнее?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Склоняются оба слова:
И. п. инженер-программист
Р. п. инженера-программиста
Д. п. инженеру-программисту
В. п. инженера-программиста
Т. п. инженером-программистом
П. п. об инженере-программисте

Answer (score 0):

Склоняются оба слова, т.к. второе является приложением и выражено нарицательным именем существительным. Сравните: газета "Правда", газету "Правда" и т.д.